# Как перевести "price match"?

Tags: перевод, словоупотребление, этимология, выражения

Price-match, frankly, appears to almost be a single word in English, however, it is surprisingly missing from the dictionary, and translate tools don't seem to do the justice, either.

---

http://www.google.com/search?q=price+match

(Also at https://archive.today/wTksp, but results aren't as relevant as what you get in .us.)

- Walmart Ad Match Guarantee

> We're committed to providing low prices every day. On everything. So if you find a lower advertised price on an identical product, tell us and we'll match it.

- Price Match Guarantee - Best Buy

> The Best Buy Price Match Guarantee ensures we won't be beat on price. We'll match the product prices of key online and local competitors.

- Shop with Confidence | Target Corporate

> Price match may be requested prior to your purchase. Simply bring in proof of the current lower price, your original receipt and we'll match the price at the Guest ...

- Amazon.com Help: About Price Matching

> Amazon.com consistently works toward maintaining competitive prices on everything we carry and will match the price of other retailers for some items.

- Price Match Guarantee - Staples

> Get answers to your questions about Staples' price match guarantee, how to find deals and offers, and the process for buying and redeeming gift cards.

- Price Match Guarantee, We Match Competitors - Toys"R"Us, Babies ...

> Toys"R"Us is the ultimate destination for matching competitive pricing ads. To prove it, we're matching competitors' in-store pricing on ALL products in our store!

- RPromise | Price Match | RadioShack www.radioshack.com/rpromise
  ‎

  > The RadioShack RPromise eliminated the need to shop around because we will match the price so you get the best deal! RadioShack.
- Price Match Policy - Office Supplies, Furniture, Technology at Office ...  www.officedepot.com/a/customerservice/lowprice/
  ‎

  > Office Depot/OfficeMax stores and Officedepot.com/OfficeMax.com will gladly match the price on a new identical item sold by any retailer who sells products in  ...
- 5 Price-Match Policies You Should Read Closely - US News

> Dec 15, 2014 ... But price matching isn't always as easy as it sounds. Due to long lists of exclusions, it's often hard to tell when your purchase qualifies.

Comment: Может `соответствие цены`?

Comment: @Dmitry, Тогда уж лучше "сопостовление", а не "соответствие".  Но очень странно звучит.

Comment: Если в контексте `Price Match Guarantee`, то это `гарантия лучшей цены`.

Comment: @cnst, guess, it is not a common practice in Russia (actually I knew about such phenomenon from your answer), that's why there's no appropriate word for this. As you see in answers, different retailers name similar rules differently.

Comment: @Dmitry, лучшая цена is different from price match.

Comment: @Ivan, you are right, Russian retailers don't practice price match on regular basis.

Comment: it's not ubiquitous within the US of A, either, it's just something that a lot of the bigger retailers do have; small retailers never have it, even in the US

Answer (score 5):

"Price match guarantee" in advertising campaigns is usually translated as *Гарантия лучшей цены* or sometimes *Гарантия наилучшей цены*

> Гарантия наилучшей цены распространяется на самые низкие доступные тарифы эконом-классе и бизнес-классе KLM и Northwest Airlines.   ([KLM](http://www.klm.com/travel/ru_ru/plan_and_book/ticket_information/best_price_guarantee/index.htm))

*Гарантия низкой цены* is also used in the marketing (google finds it on [ozon.ru](http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/20290569/) and on several hotel booking sites), although *лучшая цена* seems to be more more popular. 
For a native speaker all these variants are pretty much equivalent: they reasonable ok and convey their meaning.

"Price match" as the process of checking the competitors' prices does not have a coined term in Russian. I would say «сверить цены»

> цены можно сверить на сайте pricerunner.co.uk

Comment: i think a proper answer would be more complete and with some sample usage; e.g. how do you say, "we price match" / "do you price match?" etc.  from your answer, especially for "лучшая цена", it's unclear to me how to compose such a sentence (without also using the word "гарантия", for example).

Comment: @cnst,  I've expanded the answer and added some examples, hope it is more useful now

Answer (score 4):

М.Видео использует понятие *продажа товара по цене конкурента*:http://www.mvideo.ru/ppc

Comment: A good reference point.  Mvideo is a big brick&mortar retailer out of Moscow (I see they now in a few regional cities, too, as well as the internet), but we probably need a few more references for a complete answer.

Answer (score 3):

Another example is "Защита цены" by "Эльдорадо" (another big Russian retailer): http://www.eldorado.com.ua/low_price (it's an ukrainian site but the page is in Russian).

Also sometimes "гарантия низких цен" can be used in the meaning of the "price matching" too.

To summarize, Russian market still has no common term for "price matching".

Comment: good, but probably need a few more examples for a proper answer

Answer (score 0):

Cловосочетание `прайс-мэтч` весьма популярно в русскоязычном интернете в Америке и Канаде.
В последнее время, это словосочетание начало проникать и в собственно российский интернет. Так например, на сайте [babyblog.ru](https://www.babyblog.ru/community/housedesign/post/3193383) от 26.07.2016 находим следующую фразу:

> `... магазин, который делает прайс-мэтч (то есть дает гарантию честной цены)`

Отметим, что перевод `гарантия честной цены` тоже понятен и годен к употреблению.

Comment: Ориентировка на популярность того или иного словосточетания в русскоязычных англофонских сообществах может сыграть дурную службу. Турка вместо индюшки, салмон вместо сёмги, взять автобус и так далее.

Comment: Тут, впрочем, имени одной сёмги (из Атлантического океана) будет недостаточно - есть же и кета, горбуша, чавыча, нерка и т.д. (все - лососи Тихого океана). Взять автобус, кстати, можно, договорившись с водителем.